# What section of the CDI spec says that a bean type of String "matches" a required type of String?

Tags: cdi

The [CDI specification says](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#performing_typesafe_resolution), in part:

> A bean is assignable to a given injection point if:
>
> - The bean has a bean type that matches the required type. For this purpose, primitive types are considered to match their corresponding wrapper types in java.lang and array types are considered to match only if their element types are identical. Parameterized and raw types are considered to match if they are identical or if the bean type is assignable to the required type, as defined in [Assignability of raw and parameterized types](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#assignable_parameters).

Consider the type denoted by `java.lang.String`.  Let this be a value for a bean type `B` and a required type `R`.

How does `B` "match" `R`, given that `java.lang.String` is neither a primitive type, a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8), nor a [parameterized type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)? Does CDI incorrectly assume that the type denoted by `java.lang.String` is a raw type? Certainly [Weld takes this interpretation](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/c538ec4f6a1a37a89bc3afa5c59babe6597c01da/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/resolution/BeanTypeAssignabilityRules.java#L75-L77).

Comment: I'd assume it follows the `java.lang` wrappers train of thought, and there's docs [like this one](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#legal_bean_types:~:text=Additionally%2C%20extension%20methods%20annotated%20%40Enhancement%20may%20declare%20parameters%20of%20the%20following%20types%3A) that imply it's a bit of a special case. But I don't know.

Comment: My guess is that we should pay attention to the very first sentence. We expect that a bean of type `String` can be injected to an injection point of type `String` or `CharSequence` (I won't take `Serializable`, `Comparable` into account). For such an injection point, the bean "*matches the required type*", so it is injected.

Comment: For fun, try to find the definition of "match" for non-primitive, non-generic reference types.

Comment: For more fun, note that `String` does _not_ "match" `CharSequence` as you imply. (Obviously if the bean in question reports two bean types, `String` and `CharSequence`, one of them, in practice, "matches" a receiver type parameter (argument) of `CharSequence` (`CharSequence` "matches" `CharSequence`), but what that "match" is is undefined, since `CharSequence` is neither primitive nor generic. Is it `equals()`? Is it `==`? Is it the JLS notion of "same type"? Do annotations affect it or not affect it? And so on.